# Create array from dynamically generated select textfields jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a repeating table row with a select list. I want to create an array from the number of select textfields a user has generated. I am using .each function to iterate through all the select textfields.  Here is the code I am using. The id of the dynamically created list is "countrylist"

```
$("#Submitcountry").click(function(){ 

$("#countrylist").each(function() {
    var countrylist= [$("#countrylist").val()];
    //var countrylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
    alert(countrylist);

});});
```

As from the above, I want to see the values that I have selected. The only problem is that the alert only shows the first row. All help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## countrylist -> .countrylist

id should be one in a html page.
So, you have to change id countrylist into class countrylist, I think.

```
<input class="countrylist" name="ctlist1"></input>
<input class="countrylist" name="ctlist2"></input>
<input class="countrylist" name="ctlist3"></input>
<input class="countrylist" name="ctlist4"></input>
<input class="countrylist" name="ctlist5"></input>
...

$(".countrylist").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
...
});
```